# Websphere application server 8.5 can be installed on Ubuntu 12.04? and how?

Tags: 12.04

If WAS can be installed on Ubuntu, how to config & install?

Comment: Could you add more information/links/words to your question? It will be more easy to understand you, and you'll get better answers too. Currently, you're title is more detailed than the body. Just navigating a bit in the site, you'll note that is not common. Believe me, you can write more than 60 letters in the body without problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the next link you have the Linux distributions offically supported by WebSphere Application Server 8.5

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1307977887217&osPlatform=Linux

Only AsianLinux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Suse Linux Enterprise are officialy supported, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Though Ubuntu to is not an supported OS by IBM for WebSphere, it is possible to install WebSphere Application Server (WAS) 8.5 on Ubuntu for development environment.

1. Prerequisites

You need to install some prerequisites packages. Run following command to install the same.

> sudo apt-get install libxtst6 libgtk2.0-0 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386
>   libgtk2.0-0:i386 libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni:i386 libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni:i386
>   libstdc++6:i386

Change the default shell.
sudo mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.org
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

2. Download the binaries from IBM Web site.
3. Extract the binaries to a temp location.
4. Start Installation Manager.
5. Add repository.config file.You will get this file in the extracted binaries.
6. Click on Install button to start the installation

Source : [How to Install WebSphere Application Server on Ubuntu](http://www.techienote.com/install-was-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IBM Websphere Application Server Network Deployment now supports for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS since version **8.5.5.5**

http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1345529544358&osPlatform=Linux